# Vb.net conditional linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq, if-statement

In this query against a datatable i'm trying to do some conditional filtering.
The check against Timeband(index N) should only be done when the Index exists. (the base code only had three item fields, i've converted them to a simple list)

```
Dim res As DataTable =
    (
        From dr As DataRow In dtTimedRow.AsEnumerable()
        Select dr
        Where
        (TimeBands.Count > 0 AndAlso
         dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) >= TimeBands(0).StartTime
         And dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) <= TimeBands(0).EndTime
        ) Or
        (TimeBands.Count > 1 AndAlso
         dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) >= TimeBands(1).StartTime
         And dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) <= TimeBands(1).EndTime
        ) Or
        (TimeBands.Count > 2 AndAlso
         dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) >= TimeBands(2).StartTime
         And dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) <= TimeBands(2).EndTime)
    ).CopyToDataTable()
```

The above code triggers an Exception if the count = 1. It executes the code next to imeBands.Count > 1 which it should not. What would be the correct solution for this code.

In the mean time i've added a simple filter function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use [`And`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) when you should be using [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx):

> TimeBands.Count > 2 
>   **AndAlso** dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) >= TimeBands(2).StartTime (= cond1)
>   **And** dr.Field(Of Short)(fldStarttime) <= TimeBands(2).EndTime   (= cond2)

Since `And` and `AndAlso` [have the same operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx), this is evaluated left-to-right as follows:

> (TimeBands.Count > 2 **AndAlso** cond1) **And** cond2

`And` does not short-circuit, i.e., the right-hand side of the expression (cond2) is always evaulated, yielding an exception when `TimeBands.Count <= 2`. Change all your `And`s to `AndAlso`s, and you should be fine:

> TimeBands.Count > 2 **AndAlso** cond1 **AndAlso** cond2

An alternative would be to put parenthesis like this:

> TimeBands.Count > 2 **AndAlso** (cond1 **And** cond2)

but that's just wasting performance. Since cond1 and cond2 don't have side effects, there's no reason to avoid short-circuiting. For the same reasons, I recommend to also change your `Or`s to the short-circuiting variant `OrElse`.

Comment: You beat me to it!  I was going to suggest this same thing.

Comment: Oof I should have seen that one myself